# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'template' of null popover.js

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-popover

I am noticing an error when I trigger the `.popover('dispose');` function the error happens when I scroll up and down page and it slows my page right down. The function behaves as it should and dismisses the popover but this is the error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'template' of null` popover.js 
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSlDM.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSlDM.png)

My function

```
$('#country').focus(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#country").popover('hide');
    $("#country").popover('disable');
    $("#country").popover('dispose');
});
```

I have implemented a dynamic popover and I needed to add in a function similar to the above on focus the input field as the popover message keeps appearing after its done its job.

```
var allCountries = ['a', 'b', 'c', ...];
var mispelledCountryMsg = "misspelled error message...";

$('#country').focusout(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.each(allCountries, function (x) {
       if (inp.value !== allCountries[x]) {
            $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
            $('#country').attr('data-content', mispelledCountryMsg).popover('show');
            disableFormFields();
       } 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use {'trigger': 'manual'}

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({'trigger': 'manual'});
```