# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'template') on Bootstrap tooltip.dispose()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-5

I am trying to build a simple React web app that utilizes Bootstrap. Specifically, I was trying to use its tooltips component. I initialize every tooltip on a page using a custom hook with some tweaks to the code found in the [Bootstrap Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/tooltips/#example-enable-tooltips-everywhere) like so:

```js
function useInitializeTooltips({ trigger = "hover focus" } = {}) {
  useEffect(() => {
    document.querySelectorAll(`[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]`)
    .forEach(
      (tooltipTriggerElement) => new Tooltip(tooltipTriggerElement, { trigger })
    );
}

export default useInitializeTooltips;
```

However, later on I realized using the code *as is* causes "ghost" tooltips to persist on re-renders  (e.g. when some state has changed) and even on page redirects (using [react-router v5](https://v5.reactrouter.com/)). These can only be removed on page reloads. That's why I perform some cleanup on unmount and now the code looks like so:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const initializedTooltipList = [
    ...document.querySelectorAll(`[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]`)
  ].map(
    (tooltipTriggerElement) => new Tooltip(tooltipTriggerElement, { trigger })
  );

  // Dispose all initialized tooltips on component unmount
  return () => initializedTooltipList.forEach((tooltip) => tooltip.dispose());
});
```

Now the bugged tooltips are gone but this creates a new problem. I get the following error when a tooltip is still **showing** and a re-render happens:

```
tooltip.js:371 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'template')
    at Tooltip.getTipElement (tooltip.js:371)
    at Tooltip._cleanTipClass (tooltip.js:705)
    at complete (tooltip.js:323)
    at execute (index.js:251)
    at HTMLDivElement.handler (index.js:273)
    at triggerTransitionEnd (index.js:100)
    at index.js:279
```

[Actual error stacktrace screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIaln.png)

This has been bugging me for a while now so I've looked around but found nothing on my particular circumstance. I did find [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57173408/uncaught-in-promise-typeerror-cannot-read-property-template-of-null-popover) and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67012775/17149207) that says to provide a 'manual' trigger option on init. However, from what I understand, in my app I am not manually triggering it myself, but manually *disposing*. Either way, I want to avoid manually triggering it if possible. I would also like to avoid using the [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/overlays/#tooltips) component library if I can.

What's more, most articles I've found are using JQuery which I know next to nothing about. I've also tried digging into the bootstrap code itself but the only clue I found seems to be pointing to the fact that `this._config`, which I assume is the internal config it uses for init, somehow becomes `null` at some point in the component lifecycle. I wonder if I'm doing this the right way.

Link for a codesandbox with details on how to reproduce the error [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/bootstrap-tooltip-dispose-typeerror-phj98).

I am still quite new to web development and have been developing for just a little over 3 months, so if there is some points that need clarification or my understanding was fundamentally wrong, please feel free to point it out!

Comment: Hey @Danry, I ran into the same issue (with bootstrap popover, which is based on tooltip). Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Triggering the show and hide manually seems to solve the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54726603/bootstrap-tooltip-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-trigger-of-null?noredirect=1&lq=1